# Hibernate Return integer value

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, spring-mvc, hql

I am new to hibernate . I want to pass 2 column values and want hibernate to return primary key of that table.

```
String queryString = "select perId from Permission where document.docId=1 and user.id=2";
return getHibernateTemplate().find(queryString);
```

But this method return List.
How can i return int value.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the uniqueResult() method in Query. see [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Hibernate/UniqueResultHQL.htm) for an example or read the api [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#uniqueResult%28%29).

Here is an example. Replace the place holders as need to use them.

```
    sessionFactory = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Query query = session
            .createQuery("select value from table where ...");
    query.setParameters("param1", value1);
    result = (Type) query.uniqueResult();
```

Comment: Make sure that the query will give you only 1 result. It will trow NonUniqueResultException - if there is more than one matching result.

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like:

```
 String sql = "select count(*) from table where ...";
 BigDecimal count = (BigDecimal) hibernateTemplate.execute(
   new HibernateCallback() { 
    public Object doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException {
     SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
     return (BigDecimal) query.uniqueResult();
    }});
 return count;
```

Comment: What are the benefits of this approach?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way using addScalar:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select value from table where param1 = :param1").addScalar("value", Type);
query.setParameters("param1", value1);
result = (Type) query.uniqueResult();
```

Example of String:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select value from table where param1 = :param1").addScalar("value", StandardBasicTypes.STRING);
query.setParameters("param1", value1);
result = (String) query.uniqueResult();
```