# return a value instead of list from table using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am a newbie with hibernate I hope you guys can help me out with my little problem.
I want to have a single value being returned as a value and not as a List fromt the database. I am using hibernate for this but I don't know how to do it, this is what I got so far:

this topic: [Hibernate Return integer value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858696/hibernate-return-integer-value) didn't really help me because I don't use sessions, and query.uniqueResult() didn't work for me because it doens't recognize the method uniqueResult(), you can see the libraries/class/method I am using in the examble below.

```
import java.sql.*;
import org.hibernate.*;

import org.hibernate.criterion.*;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

public class Persistence
{

public void RegisterWorkHours(TimeRegistration object)
    {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("timereg");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        String q = "SELECT id FROM tbl_employee WHERE bsn = @bsn";
        Query query = em.createQuery(q);
        query.setParameter("@bsn", object.getEmployee().getBsn());

    //And here I want to have a single value being returned as a value and not as a List.

        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(object);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();

    }
}
```

Problem defined:
The problem is that I got id defined in my Employee class and its auto_incremented. But I got no setters to it because I don't want the user to be forced to enter a unique id of that user. But I do want to be able to get the id from the employee table where bsn equals the  given bsn value from the object so that I can Register the amount of hours a certain employee(id) have worked on a certain project(id).

Comment: Sounds like your `bsn` value is not unique, which indicates to me that you need to revisit your design. Why aren't you using pure JPA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `uniqueResult()` method on the `javax.persistence.Query` interface (which is what your code is using). To get a single result use either `getFirstResult()` or `getSingleResult()`. But note that neither is particularly useful in your case for these reasons:

- Invoking getFirstResult() will return you the first element in the
  collection returned by your query. Which may or may not be the
  element you were looking for.
- Invoking `getUniqueResult()` expects the query to return
  ***exactly*** one item, and will throw an exception if the collection returned is empty, or has more than one entry.

If your `bsn` value is truly unique then use `getUniqueResult()`, but if its not then you need to revisit your design.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my bsn value is 100% unique so the query will only return one value so i could use the getUniqueResult() method but what library do i need to add before i can use that function ? And i got another general question, how can i send PMś to other stackoverflow users ?

Comment: The `getUniqueResult()` is present on Query class since JPA 1.0, which  you already have if you are using `EntityManager` and `EntityManagerFactory`. As to private messages, they don't exist on Stack Overflow. You could make a request for their addition at http://meta.stackexchange.com.