# Getting an error while using "Generics" in Hibernate Query

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate in my project and using "Query" Like below.

```
Query query = em.createQuery("delete from User where name=:name");
query.setParameter("name", "Zigi");
int deleted = query.executeUpdate();
```

I'm getting the result. When i'm using generics Like below

```
Query<?> query = em.createQuery("delete from User where name=:name");
query.setParameter("name", "Zigi");
int deleted = query.executeUpdate();
```

getting the result because "?" is something as wildcard (or) it will accept any datatype

when i'm using the code as below getting some error( java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Update/delete queries cannot be typed ). i'm using Integer datatype because createQuery return number when it's executed

```
Query<Integer> query = em.createQuery("delete from User where name=:name", Integer.class);
query.setParameter("name", "Zigi");
int deleted = query.executeUpdate();
```

Any suggestions. I have to use Generics with specific datatype in it like above code.

thanks in advance

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Update/delete queries cannot be typed

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `executeUpdate` does not allow you to use a typed query.

Instead you can use uniqueResult, and cast to the type that you want:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("delete from User where name=:name");
query.setParameter("name", "Zigi");
int deleted = (Integer) query.uniqueResult();
```

Referencing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7858731/3271729)