# How to Retrieve a Single Value from Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-mvc, fluent-nhibernate

Goal:
How to use Fluent Nhibernate in order retrieve the value 1 in a variable by using Stored procedure.

Problem:

```
        using (NHibernate.ISession session = FluentNHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
        {
            var result = session.CreateSQLQuery("exec test");
        }
```

It does not work, what code am I missing in order to retrieve the value 1 in the variable result?

I'm using C# and not java code.

Thank you!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[test]
as  
Begin  

    SELECT 1
End
GO
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate Return integer value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858696/hibernate-return-integer-value)

Comment: Creating/preparing a query is not executing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
var result = session.CreateSQLQuery("exec test").UniqueResult();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!